# How do I turn on and off the database connection with two different functions in php?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to make a function that will firstly sets up the database connection using mysqli. Then I can share the `$conn` variable for my database queries and close it once I am done.

How do I share the `$conn` variable between two different functions? Should I make it into a global variable?

**Establish connection**

```
function setcon()
{
  $conn= new mysqli($server,$username,$pass,$db);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die($conn->connect_error);
  }
}
```

**Destroy connection**

```
function endcon()
{
  $conn->close();
}
```

Comment: not using `()` in `setcon()` and `endcon()` is typo mistake ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Rishi, I am typing this on a phone, it's hard to notice errors this way.

Comment: You can use class variable if you are using. like `$this->conn` to set and destroy

Comment: Create a php document called 'functions', 'commonTools', or something like that. Include it in the top of your php files, along with session_start() and other functions that is of your interest to have. 

That way you will have them in all your project, you just need to include it in your files.

Comment: @SrAxi, that is what I am doing. I need help to create and destroy database connections.

Answer (score 0):

Having a global variable is not considered a good practice.

It depends on you project scope and architecture, but I would suggest to have the database connection as the return value of the connect function (setcon in your case). Every function that uses the database needs to be passed the connection variable as an argument.

For more complex projects you could do it the object oriented way and construct a database connection object that also takes care all the common checks and error handling. This would be recommended if you plan to switch to a different database at some point.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
function connect($server, $username, $pass, $db)
{
    closeConnect();

    $dbName = $db;
    $dc = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $pass);
    if ( ! $dc) {
        echo "Connection to $dbName failed!";
    }
    mysqli_select_db($dbName, $dc);
}

function closeConnect()
{
    global $dc;
    if ($dc)
        @mysqli_close($dc);
    $dc = null;
}
```

Hope it helps you!